# How to Sort a PictureCollection by Date

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application I have the need to call images from the `Saved Pictures` album on the phone and retrieve the most recent that have been saved. I need to guarantee that I collect the most recent images by date. Currently I am just reversing the collection and gathering the pictures, but I realized that this does not in fact always get the most recent pictures because they are sorted by name (from what I can tell) in the default Saved Pictures album in the PhotosHub. How might I pull and sort this collection by date so I can pull the most recent?

```
private PictureCollection _pictures = null;

public void GetImages()
{
    using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
    {
        foreach (PictureAlbum album in library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums)
        {
            if (album.Name == "Saved Pictures")
            {
                _pictures = album.Pictures;

                if(_pictures != null)
                {
                    //search for the most recent pictures in the album
                    foreach (var p in _pictures.Reverse()) //need to sort by date first
                    {
                        //Do something with pictures

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with following:

1. Change `_pictures` to be `List<Picture>` instead of `PictureCollection`
2. Change `GetImages` method to:

   ```
   public void GetImages()
   {
       using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
       {
           var savedPictures = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums.First(a => a.Name == "Saved Pictures");

           _pictures = savedPictures.Pictures.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```